# Does WebSphere cache configuration files for Spring applications?

Tags: java, spring, websphere

I'm using WebSphere 7.0.0.13 for AIX. Surprisingly I find WebSphere occasionally reports certain XML tags (such as the one for `<tx:transactionManager>`) to be missing an ending tag, though I'm pretty sure it has the ending tag.

The phenomenon is more likely to happen to have the process of WAS manually killed. I doubt if WAS is caching our Spring config files somewhere?

Comment: only pretty sure the end tag is there? what does the file on disk say?

Comment: Was does not cache it in fact there is not such caching any where. Like Matt said check the physical file and shut down WAS during changes(not needed but I do it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is doubtful that WebSphere does anything special for Spring XML files; it doesn't "know about" Spring, AFAIK.

It is also doubtful that Spring does anything special to cache its XML files; there would be no performance advantage in Spring caching files that are typically read / used once on webapp startup and not again.

If you are really getting stale XML files, I expect that the problem is something to do with the way your updates are getting deployed to the webapp.  Maybe the files are not being copied across, or not being unpacked, or the webapp is not restarting properly.